# Xcode Error Message - No visible @interface for ViewController declares the selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a very simple method that allows me to specify the name of a UIButton and then set its title. I previously had the method in my main ViewController which worked fine. But then I have decided to create a new file called CustomMethods.h/m and put all of my methods in there.

As soon as I have moved the method across and #import the header into the main view controller I am getting the error message below

```
No visible @interface for ViewController declares the selector 'SetTitleOfButtonNamed:withTitle:'
```

In my CustomMethods file I have created my method as follows:

```
-(void)setTitleOfButtonNamed:(UIButton *)button withTitle:(NSString *)buttonTitle
{
    [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
}
```

In the viewDidLoad of the main ViewController I am trying to call this method and set the button title as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *btnOneTitle = @"Button 1";
    [self setTitleOfButtonNamed:buttonOne withTitle:btnOneTitle]; // ERROR OCCURS HERE
}
```

Before I copied the method into its own file it worked perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: No sorry, that is purely a typo in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are still calling setTitleOfButtonNamed on "self" which is the ViewController.  You need to call it from the CustomMethods class that implements the method now.

```
[self setTitleOfButtonNamed:buttonOne withTitle:btnOneTitle];
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed the methods to class methods rather than instance and called from the class where it was defined. Works perfectly.

Comment: Would you explain more please?